# Databricks Pyspark code with Substring and suffix(''), then List[] table names

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, substr, pathlib

OBJECTIVE: pull a list of table names from an Azure Gen2 container, then ingest CSVs into Delta Lake.

So far I have this:

1. In Databricks use `%fs ls /mnt/myPath/` to list the CSV files in a table, then manually download that table to local Excel, then upload that to Databricks / Data / Create Table called "table_list".
2. Make a dataframe from that table of file names with

```py
df=spark.sql("""substr(path FROM 43) AS table_names 
FROM table_list WHERE path LIKE '%.csv' """)
```

3. Transform the df to a Python List with

```py
my_table_list=list(df.select('table_names').toPandas()['table_names']
```

4. Create a new Python List[] with no .csv suffix

```py
from pathlib import Path

for n in my_table_list
filename = Path(n)
filename_no_suffix = filename.with_suffix('')
my_table_list_2.append(filename_no_suffix)
```

5. Now send this list to my read/write/create function.

But there has got to be a better way!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The above code is giving me a list with [PosixPath('table_name_1'), PosixPath('table_name_2'), PosixPath('table_name_3')] which is not really what I want.  Just want a list of table names ['table_name_1', 'table_name_2','table_name_3']

Comment: So Databricks to Excel than back to Databricks. What is happening inside Excel?

Comment: You can remove suffix in pyspark without using Pandas nor Path. `df.withColumn('nosuffix', F.regex_replace('table_names', '.csv', '')`.  
Then, read/write/create, does it have to pass as python list?  or can you use `df.forEach` or Pyspark functions?

Comment: Thank you Emma.  I will test and let you know.  I do think df.forEach or Pyspark function would be a better way to go.  -------  The base question is how do I pull a list of file names and schemas from ADLS Gen2 into a Databricks Notebook?  The rest is ready to go.

Comment: Luiz, I think we'll find a way to cut out the Excel steps entirely.